# Is there a simple way to initialize a data member that is a dynamic array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic-arrays

As below, a string pointer is initialized using syntax `Line(string arg): foo{new string(arg)} {}`, but not for a dynamic array, it failes to use `Line(int* arg): p_matrix{new int[3](arg)} {}` (let's temporarily forget the rule of five)

How do I initialize a dynamic array that itself is a data member of a class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Line
{
    public:

        string* foo;
        Line(string arg): foo{new string(arg)} {}

        int* p_matrix;
        Line(int* arg): p_matrix{new int[3](arg)} {}
};

int main( )
{
    Line line {"bar"};
    cout << *(line.foo);

    int matrix[3] = {1,2,3};
    Line line2 {matrix};
    cout << line2.p_matrix[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can write `new int[3]{arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]}`.  If you don't want to do this then you have to write a loop in the constructor. To avoid this sort of issue, use arrays and raw pointers less, and uses classes like `string` and `array` more.

Comment: @M.M Sad to know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
Line(int* arg): p_matrix{new int[3](arg)} {}
```

is trying to assign an `int*` to an `int`.

You could initialize the array as follows:

```
Line(int* arg)
: p_matrix{new int[3]()} 
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
   {
      p_matrix[i] = arg[i];
   }
}
```

This is not very safe.

If you wanted to initialize it in the initializer list, I suspect you could use lambas. I am not too familiar with this though, so maybe somebody else could explain.

Comment: Why do you think it is not very safe?

Comment: @BenVoigt Could you tell me how do I write the static helper function you mentioned?

Comment: @Nicolas: Roughly `static int* copy_matrix(int* src, int N) { int* dst = new int[N];for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i) dst[i] = src[i]; return dst; }` and then `Line(int* arg) : p_matrix{copy_matrix(arg, 3)} {}`  In this way all the assignments are performed before the initialization of `p_matrix`, which allows (for example) const qualification such as `const int* p_matrix;`

Comment: @Nicholas I meant mainly meant that the use of raw pointers is unsafe. It is also not very extendable, if you want to have an array of length other than 3.